# Remove drupal module javascript, replace with my own in template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am trying to remove the default lightbox.js file coming from the Lightbox2 module, by using template.php, and load in my own. I would like to do this via template.php if possible, and not place this code in a custom module. I am adding my javascript file, then unsetting the module javascript file. The problem is $vars['scripts'] isn't getting replaced with the output from $js, and still outputting the module javascript. krumo($js) shows the default lightbox.js removed. Below is what I have in template_preprocess_page. Thanks in advance.

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/resources/js/lightbox.js", 'theme');
$js = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL, 'header'); //get header js files in an array
$lightbox_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'lightbox2');
unset($js['module'][$lightbox_path . '/js/lightbox.js']); //unset lightbox default js
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $js);
```

Comment: You should have a look at my response, user310404, as I modified it to include what I think is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's take another look at it, then.

Having just looked at http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6 a second time, I note that the lightbox code is probably in

```
$js['header']['module'][$lightbox_path .'/js/lightbox.js']
```

and not in

```
$js['module'][$lightbox_path .'/js/lightbox.js'].
```

I suggest sneaking a `dpm($js)` in before your 'unset' call, and then hit refresh a couple of times until it shows up, and make sure you've got the exact correct combination of $scope and $type to find the lightbox code at.

(Note: dpm() is a function provided by the devel module, which I guess I'm assuming your'e already using.  If you're not, then `drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($js, TRUE) .'</pre>);` will do as well.

Comment: Yes, it's written as 

function dev_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {